# Does DeleteAsync throw when file is in use by the UWP app and cannot be deleted

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I am trying to use DeleteAsync (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.istorageitem.deleteasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Storage_IStorageItem_DeleteAsync_Windows_Storage_StorageDeleteOption_) to delete files in the app folder.

```
winrt::StorageFolder localFolder = winrt::ApplicationData::Current().LocalFolder();
```

Doc for this method does not say anything about what happens if file cannot be deleted for example because it is being used the UWP app. Any idea about the behavior? Does it throw?

Comment: Errors in C++/WinRT are reported as C++ exceptions. Exceptions raised from coroutines are re-thrown on the calling thread.

Comment: But does this method DeleteAsync throw anything when file is in use? Help doc does not say anything about that.

Comment: In general, it will throw `System.IO.FileLoadException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.'

Comment: `System.IO.FileLoadException` is a .NET type. There is no .NET in the Windows Runtime nor the UWP. All errors are reported by way of `HRESULT` values at the ABI that different language projections translate to different things. C++/WinRT translates failure codes to C++ exceptions of type [`hresult_error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/error-handling/hresult-error) or types derived from it. If you need to find out the ABI signature of methods you can look into the respective .idl files that come with the Windows SDK (*windows.storage.idl* in this case).

Comment: So how do I know whether the file is really deleted or not if DeleteAsync is not returning anything?

Comment: The raw `DeleteAsync` method returns an `HRESULT` that gets translated into a C++ exception by C++/WinRT. You can easily verify this by trying to delete a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I am using C++Winrt. raw DeleteAsync that you mention is it some different API than https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.istorageitem.deleteasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Storage_IStorageItem_DeleteAsync_Windows_Storage_StorageDeleteOption_ this one? Can i call it in Winrt?

Comment: The ABI signatures of Windows Runtime types are not/no longer documented in Microsoft's documentation. What you are looking at is how the ABI gets projected into different languages (such as C# or C++/WinRT). There's nothing keeping you from using the raw ABI interfaces, either from C++ directly or with the use of the WRL. Either one is harder, more verbose, and easier to get wrong than the language projections (such as C++/WinRT).

Comment: But language projection (in my case C++Winrt) does not give me return info about whether file was deleted. So what option do I have to check whether the file delete operation was success or not? If ABI is not documented, how do I find the functions, parameters, return types, etc?

Comment: C++/WinRT translates failure `HRESULT` values into C++ exceptions. If you need to look up the raw ABI interface signature, have a look at the .idl files that come with the Windows SDK.

Comment: Have you tried deleting a file that you have open?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Ok, I had the file open in notepad and DeleteAsync just went ahead and deleted it. Is this expected behavior? So the error saying file is used by another process is only when we try to delete it using Windows Explorer?

Comment: Notepad presumably doesn't lock the file. There are various file sharing options when you open a file.

Comment: Any app that definitely locks the file? I will try with it

Comment: Try opening an Office doc (Word, Excel, etc.) and deleting that.